# Assert if two 2D arrays are equal

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Given two 2D arrays, how can I assert whether or not they are equal?

For example:

```
array1 = [[1,0],[2,1],[3,0]]
array2 = [[1,0],[2,1],[3,1]]
```

What is an efficient way to check whether array1 == array2?

Comment: every value at each index is identical

Answer (score 6):

If by equality you mean the array contents have same elements in the same order, then the shortest (though not the fastest) way will be:

```
JSON.stringify(array1) === JSON.stringify(array2)
```

This will work with arrays of any dimensions.

**UPDATE:** If you need a really fast algorithm then simple iteration will work better. However it is less fool-proof, hence to make it really safe and secure you'll need to spend more development time. Here is one possible solution for modern browsers:

```
function equal(array1, array2) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array1) && !Array.isArray(array2)) {
        return array1 === array2;
    }

    if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = array1.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (!equal(array1[i], array2[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The following JSPerf speed test shows the supremacy of this algorithm over the short `JSON` approach: http://jsperf.com/2d-array-comparion.

Comment: I wonder if a function dedicated specifically to the check would necessarily be faster, given most JavaScript engines have `JSON.stringify` built in now... Be an interesting http://jsperf.com...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would assume that string concatenation may be time consuming in this approach. Otherwise if speed is not important, this solution should be more than valid and no brainer. Especially if we define *efficient* as "space and dev time saving".

Comment: Well, that's basically what I'm wondering about, given it happens within the engine, the string generation may be efficient. Or not :-) Be an interesting thing to check. blenddd [makes a good point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27102807/157247) about early termination, though, which obviously the `stringify` aspect wouldn't really offer. So the answer may well relate to the frequency with which they're the same or different.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Iteration is obviously faster: http://jsperf.com/2d-array-comparion `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would always depend on the size of the array/s and on your application and usage for them. You can check for the lengths of the 2 arrays for an early termination in case of a non match, but this might be considered as an extra step if that case rarely happens.

```
boolean areEqual(array array1, array array2){
if array1.length != array2.length
    return false;
for (int i=0;i<array1.length; i++)
    if(!areEqual(array1[i], array2[i])
        return false;
return true;
}

boolean areEqual(int first, int second){
    return first == second;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what language that's meant to be (the question is about JavaScript), but other than relying on overloading (which JS doesn't have), certainly the above has the advantage of early termination.

Comment: thats more of pseudo code, I didn't notice the tag, my bad, but i guess it's easy to convert it into a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go would be to iterate all values in a nested loop, compare value by value. Use a boolean which you set to false at the first mismatch, and assert that this boolean is true in your test.