# Comparing 2d array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have two 2d arrays and the user put the length and the values of both arrays but I need to compare the elements of both arrays.

```
 if (first.length != second.length)
System.out.println("The size of the two arrays are not equals");
else
{
for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < second.length; j++)
if (first[i][j] != second[i][j])
{
 System.out.println("The two arrays are not strictly identical arrays");
 break;
}   
if(i == first.length-1)
 System.out.println("The two arrays are strictly identical arrays");
```

the problem is the user can't put all values of the second array (like the half values of the first array)

Comment: Can you share the code after the if statment and of array declaration as well? Also, what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Can you read that code in your comment? Probably not. So please: edit your question when adding information. Don't put such stuff into comments!

Comment: Just add `(first.length != 0 && (first[0].length != second[0].length))` as precondition for checking the number of columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27102807/4857588

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution in your problem is this one.By checking that first.length is equal to second.length you're checking their rows.Meanwhile when you're using j for first[i][j] j is for the columns.Imagine having second[2][3] your second for will run 2 times instead of 3 because second.length gives you the number 2.

```
for(int i = 0;i < first.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < second[i].length;j++){
         if (first[i][j] != second[i][j])
              // and you should insert the other parts of your code here
```